# Access variable in a function defined in some other function in same conroller - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, variables, scope

I am using socialite and trying to access a variable in handleProviderCallback() which has been defined in redirectToProvider() in a same controller. Its simple as that. But its not working, I have tried adding global keyword before variable but Laravel is throwing the error. Below is a sample code representation.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function redirectToProvider()
        {

        // defined a variable with some value - this value is dynamic changes every time a user logs in.

        $someVariable= 'some value';

        }


    public function handleProviderCallback()
        {

        //trying to access someVariable defined in the above function.


        }

}
```

Any suggestion would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You should be creating a private member instead of trying global. create private $someVariable and then access like $this->someVariable. Hope it helps

Comment: There is most likely a better solution for this but a global variable

Comment: @MuhammadUmair can you please provide a sample code that will further explain your comment? That would be helpful. thanks

Comment: I will leave it here too: You are deep into [XY](You are deep into XY problem. Edit your question with actual code and error you have) problem. Edit your question with actual code and error you have.

Comment: @Tpojka edited. please see the edited question now

Comment: What provider/package is used?

Comment: @Tpojka Socialite.

Comment: Is any third party package used for that except `laravel/socialite`?

Comment: none. Just socialte. Can you please use teamviewer/anydesk to see my code? or we can move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210612/discussion-between-tpojka-and-faisal-shani).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it. Take a lookk to this piece of code:

```php
// declare first
private $someVariable = null;

private funcA()
{
// defined a variable with some value - this value is dynamic changes every time a user logs in.
$this->someVariable= 'some value';
}

private funcB()
{
//trying to access someVariable defined in the above function.
}
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: so you saying I have to define the fucntions as private? and the variable should be defined before any function like at the above of all function just below after declaring the class?

Comment: @FaisalShani, basically yes. You can define a variable/function as private/public/protected. If the variables are closed to the controller, use private.

Comment: @FaisalShani Thats exactly what I suggested in my comment above.

Comment: is there any way without declaring the functions private? Basically I am using socialite and trying to add a variable in redirectToProvider() that will be accessed in 
handleProviderCallback(). Both are socialite built in functions and are public by default.

Comment: @FaisalShani You are deep into [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. Edit your question with actual code and error you have.

Comment: You dont have to make them private. Its up to you, If these functions are going to be accessed from outside of class, you can create them as public. You can also create a public variable.

Comment: @Tpojka edited. please see the edited question now.

Comment: @Tpojka great. just sent you a message on chat. please check

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do.

```
class LoginController extends Controller
    {
            // You can also create this as public
            private someVariable;

            public function redirectToProvider()
            {
                Assign value here
                $this->someVariable= 'some value';

             }


            public function handleProviderCallback()
            {
                 //Now you can access $this->someVariable


             }

        }
```